# ionic 2 BEST IDE?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ide, ionic2, mobile-application

I am going to create a mobile app using ionic2(angular2).
Can anyone suggest a good IDE? (Netbeens, Eclipse and so on...)

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/editors_and_ides/

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Code , WebStorm are two mostly used .VS Code is free and very good for angular 2 .

Comment: visual studio code is better...